# php .htaccess shows 404 instead of redirecting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get my .htaccess file to redirect everything to index.php and use the url parameters to show what I need it to.

If I type in something along the lines of "http://localhost/2351/515" then it just shows 404 not found instead of redirecting with the params.

index.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['params'])) {
        $params = explode( "/", $_GET['params'] );
        print_r($params);
        exit("YUP!");
    }
?>
```

.htaccess

```
ServerSignature Off

Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Firstly, you are passing `(.*)` to the `p` parameter, and not the `param` one. So you are reading the incorrect thing. However, that wouldn't cause a 404, which is probably because mod_rewrite may be disabled, or `AllowOverride All` isn't set in your virtual host configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: The OP wants to read the `param` query parameter. Doing this does not create that parameter.